# How to use SOCKSify proxy with auth

Tags: ruby

```
def tcp_socket(address, port,p_username = nil, p_password = nil)
  addr = TCPSocket::SOCKSConnectionPeerAddress.new("server_address", 14193,"username","passowrd", address)
  TCPSocket.open(addr, port, self.source_address)
end
```

This code not work for auth connection.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the Help Center topics on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). I'd be happy to try to help, but statements like "this code not work" are not diagnostically useful. Please explain what you are attempting to do, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and why the outcome you get does not do what you need.

Comment: "code not work" is not a very detailed diagnostic. Can you elaborate on that?